# Ajax Request Loop and Wait Until Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a more efficient way to write the following? I need to loop through objList and pass the UnqKey to wfrmPrint. On success of that I then have to loop though the Pages. I am looping through the pages and unqkeys by passing a integer and checking to see if it is less than the length.  I tried to use .when.apply taken from http://www.tentonaxe.com/index.cfm/2011/9/22/Using-jQuerywhen-with-a-dynamic-number-of-objects, but it was loading the unqkeys and then the pages.

```
//sample objList
[
    {
        "UnqKey": 1,
        "Pages": [
            "wfrmSet1Page1.aspx",
            "wfrmSet1Page2.aspx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "UnqKey": 2,
        "Pages": [
            "wfrmSet2Page1.aspx",
            "wfrmSet2Page2.aspx",
            "wfrmSet3Page2.aspx",
            "wfrmSet4Page2.aspx"
        ]
    }
]

function Loop(iListIndex) {
var obj = objList[iListIndex];

if (iListIndex < objList.length) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'wfrmPRINT.aspx?action=LoadSession&UnqKey=' + obj.UnqKey, //load session that is used in wfrmSet1Pages.. or wfrmSet2Pages..
        success: function () {
            AddPages(obj, iListIndex, 0);
        }
    })
} else {
    alert('Done');
}
}

function AddPages(obj, iListIndex, iPageIndex) {
if (iPageIndex < obj.Pages.length) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: obj.Pages[iPageIndex] + '?Print=1', //load html 
        async: true,
        success: function (html) {
            iPageIndex++
            AddPages(obj, iListIndex, iPageIndex);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Failed!');
            iPageIndex++
            AddPages(obj, iListIndex, iPageIndex);
        }
    });
} else {
    iListIndex++
    Loop(iListIndex);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: If you want to alternate between sending to wfrmPRINT and then Print back and forth rather than sending all of one then all of another, $.when probably isn't going to be an option and your looping or a similar looping would be the alternative. However, if it would be acceptible to send all wfrmPRINT, then when all of them are done loop through and send all ?Print, that can be done with $.when.

Comment: What did not work when using `$.when`? And: do you need to fire the ajax requests sequentially or in parallel?

Comment: Could you instead possibly consolidate these requests into one or two? it would be far more efficient.

Comment: They need to be fired sequentially. When I used .when I got the following error, Unable to cast object of type 'clsSet1' to type 'clsSet2'.
Session("objSet") is being set in wfrmPRINT and on the page load of wfrmSet1Pages Dim oSet as clsSet1 = Session("objSet") and on wfrmSet2Pages Dim oSet as clsSet2 = Session("objSet").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this,

```
function getData(arr,arrindex) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'wfrmPRINT.aspx?action=LoadSession&UnqKey=' + arr[arrindex].UnqKey
    }).then(function(data){
        var deferredObj = $.Deferred(), defArr = $.map(arr[arrindex].Pages,function(page){
            return $.ajax({type: "GET", url: page + '?Print=1'});
        });
        $.when.apply(null,defArr).done(deferredObj.resolveWith).fail(deferredObj.resolveWith);
        return deferredObj.promise();
    }).done(function(){
        arrindex++;
        if (arr[arrindex]) {
            getData(arr,arrindex);
        }
        else {
            alert("done!");
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("FAIL!");
    });
}
getData(objList,0);
```

It gets each wfrm sequentially, and when each one finishes, requests all of the pages for that one at once. Somewhat of a combination between your loop and a deferred $.when

Edit: fixed `$.map` argument order

Comment: return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: page + '?Print=1'
            });
    
How would I get the data returned from the above ajax request?  In the past I have used  

  jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: page + '?Print=1'
            success: function(markup) {
                if (markup) {
    
    //load markup to div
    
    }
});

Comment: i don't get what you are saying. that's what's in my answer, without line breaks. :p

Comment: I hit enter when I was trying to add a line break :)

Comment: That data should be available in the `.done` callback at the end. do `console.log(arguments)` to see the structure it is in.